# JavaScript не устанавливается фокус в текстовое поле

Tags: javascript

Скажи пожалуйста в чем ошибка?

[КОД](http://jsfiddle.net/cV6fU/)

Есть обычное скрытое текстовое поле, и обычный блок div.

Нужно при нажатии на блок, что бы блок исчез и текстовое поле появилось с установленным указателем.

Почему у меня не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте событие **onClick**